# How to format date of json response in html angular?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

In angular html, I loop the json array using ngfor and get the birth date data through this:

```
<td>{{item.customer_info.birth_date}}</td>
```

The data will output ddMMyyyy, however I want to change the format to dd-MM-yyyy **in .html not in .ts**

Any idea how?

I have tried {{item.customer_info.birth_date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}} but it doesn't work

Comment: The date pipe uses a date as input. The problem you have is, that your input is a string.  I recommend to map the data when fetching it and store the mapped data in your component.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm you can use a string see https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#input-value but string of format `ddMMyyyy` won't work

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 'birthdate' is invalid date, when it is parsed to date. It should be in month, date, year format by default. Can you check what is the value you currently have for 'birthdate'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).